# Is it possible to define a thread within a function of an actor in Akka Actor?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka, akka-actor

Let's assume I have an actor class with a method in Akka Actor:

```
class SecureActor extends Actor{
  def methodWithThread(): Unit={
}
```

Can a run a new thread in this method? Wouldn't it be problematic regarding Akka's own threading?

```
class ThreadExample extends Thread{  
    override def run(){  
      println("Thread is running...");  
}
```

```
def methodWithThread(): Unit={
  var t = new ThreadExample()  
  t.start()
}
```

Comment: You are gonna breake the concurrency security provided by Akka for you. This case that you presented it is common to spaw multiple actors child from one single parent as a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to get sure of this. Can u demonstrate it with more detail in answer so I can accept it? @Felipe

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why you want to do this? Sounds a bit like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @yuval-itzchakov I want to block the actor and leave only the thread to send some control messages to the other actors.

Comment: Blocking an actor is a bit of going against Akka core principles. Why do you need the actor to be blocked? Can the actor just dispatch the messages to child actors?

Comment: I am implementing a function which blocks the actor until some control messages are received and prevents sending messages for security reasons. It is research based.There is also no child actors in my project's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that you are looking for how to make sure that this way that you want to create async tasks from an Akka Actor will break the Akka concurrency pattern that it provides to you, here is some very simple example based on your classes.

This is not an answer to demonstrate how to spawn child actors from a parent actor as I suggested in my commentary. And as you also said that you are interested to demonstrate how to break the Akka concurrency pattern. I suggested that you look for simple examples of how to do that. Maybe [this example](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/akka-typed-how-delegate-work-to-child-actors/) helps.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}

import scala.util.Random

object BreakingAkkaConcurrency {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("BreakingAkkaConcurrency")
    val unsecureActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[UnsecureActor], "unsecureActor")
    unsecureActor ! "1"
    unsecureActor ! "2"
    unsecureActor ! "3"
    unsecureActor ! "4"
    unsecureActor ! "5"
    unsecureActor ! "6"
    unsecureActor ! "7"
    unsecureActor ! "8"
    unsecureActor ! "9"
    unsecureActor ! "10"

    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }
}

class UnsecureActor extends Actor {
  def methodWithThread(): Unit = {
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      var t = new ThreadExample(msg)
      // by starting a new thread inside an Akka actor you break the synchronous pattern provided by Akka
      t.start()
  }
}

class ThreadExample(id: String) extends Thread {
  override def run() {
    // simulate a random computation which will potentially break the order of messages processed by Akka actors
    // This is where the Akka actors don't have control anymore.
    Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(10) * 1000)
    println(s"finished $id");
  }
}
```

the output will be in a different order than the `unsecureActor ! "1"` send messages.

```
finished 9
finished 4
finished 1
finished 7
finished 3
finished 2
finished 8
finished 5
finished 6
finished 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I ran your code and the order of received messages was the same. If I make sure that this randomness doesn't happen can I still use it? The order of messages is not of much importance in my project as I use priority message queue.

Comment: as @Tim answered, yes you can do, there is nothing blocking you to implement in this way. However, you will break the akka concurrency safeness once there is code inside the actor that potentially break it. I mean, once you or other programmer working on the same code forgets it and start a thread from your code without concurrency guarantees, the code will compile and run. Maybe you will find some problems on the result one day in the future, and this will be a Pain-In-The-neck to find the bug. So, my question to you: why are you using Akka in the end if you don't use its advantages?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got it. It is an academic research project based on Akka and I think that the whole advantages of Akka are not considered to be important by my mentors.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to start code in a separate thread from inside an Actor (e.g. using `Future`) but you have to be careful about how it interacts with Akka. The thread should not read or modify any mutable state in the Actor, and it should only communicate with the Actor by sending messages.

Comment: so, in other words, creating a thread inside an Actor (even with or without `Future`) is likely to create more possibilities to break concurrency in distributed systems if one does not use objects with immutable state. Considering that more people will work on the same code, the danger increases even more...

Comment: @Felipe Yes, using threads risks breaking concurrency. But it is possible to do it in a way that reduces the risks while retaining the benefits.

Comment: In a research based project I have to block the actor to receive some control messages ( I am aware that it is not recommended to block in Akka).
Before the `Await.result` period I want to run a thread in my actor to send some control messages to the other actors. @Tim

Comment: Never, ever call `Await.result` in the receive method of an actor. Add an `onComplete` handler to the object which sends a message containing the result of the operation to the actor. Or have a separate thread that processes control messages and forwards them to the Actor.